# "Not a function" when run with addEventListener

Tags: javascript

When I click on the button, it runs the function `fillOneLiter`. However `smallBottle.fillAndTransferTwice()` says is not a function.

When I run the `fillOneLiter` function by itself in the code without the click event, it works perfectly.

Why does it stop working when I run it through the click event?

Everything works when I run the `fillOneLiter` function without the click event.

```
class Bottle {

    constructor( maxVolume ) {
        this.maxVolume = maxVolume;
    }

    currentVolume = 0;

    empty() {
        this.currentVolume = 0;
    }

    fill(target) {
        while (this.currentVolume !== 0 && target.currentVolume !== target.maxVolume) {
            this.currentVolume--;
            target.currentVolume++;
        }
    }

    transfer(target) {
        this.fill(target);
    }

    fillAndTransfer(target) {
        this.currentVolume = this.maxVolume;
        this.fill(target);
    }

    fillAndTransferTwice(target) {
        var i;
        for ( i=0; i<=2; i++) {
            this.currentVolume = this.maxVolume;
            this.fill(target);
        }
    }
}

var fillOneLiter = (smallBottle, bigBottle) => {
    smallBottle.fillAndTransferTwice(bigBottle);

    bigBottle.empty();
}

var fillFourLiter = (smallBottle, bigBottle) => {
    smallBottle.fillAndTransferTwice(bigBottle);

    bigBottle.empty();
    smallBottle.transfer(bigBottle);
    smallBottle.fillAndTransfer(bigBottle);
}

var smallBottle = new Bottle(3);
var bigBottle = new Bottle(5);

const threeLiter = document.getElementById('small-bottle-volume');
const smallButton = document.getElementById('first-button');

smallButton.addEventListener('click', function(smallBottle, bigBottle){
    fillOneLiter(smallBottle, bigBottle);
})
```

I'm curios why the method `fillAndTransferTwice` does not work in the function `fillOneLiter` when I run that function through the click event listener. If I just run `fillOneLiter` without an event, then the method `fillAndTransferTwice` works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser's click event has no knowledge of your `Bottle` objects, and no browser is going to expect to pass those objects to an event handler.  The argument passed to an event handler is [the event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).  So in this code:

```
smallButton.addEventListener('click', function(smallBottle, bigBottle){
    fillOneLiter(smallBottle, bigBottle);
})
```

The `smallBottle` parameter in this function is an event object, which you then pass to `fillOneLiter`, which then tries to call `fillAndTransferTwice` on that event object.  That function isn't on the event object.

If you want your event handler to always use the same `Bottle` objects then you can omit the function parameters entirely and just use the page-scoped variables:

```
smallButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    fillOneLiter(smallBottle, bigBottle);
})
```

This way you don't have new `smallBottle` and `bigBottle` variables in the function's scope and instead use the variables in the higher scope.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I understand now :D

Answer (score 0):

To fix this code, just replace this:

```
smallButton.addEventListener('click', function(smallBottle, bigBottle){
    fillOneLiter(smallBottle, bigBottle);
})
```

with

```
smallButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
    fillOneLiter(smallBottle, bigBottle);
})
```

When you pass a function to `addEventListener` it is expected that the first argument to that function is an object representing the event that happened. So in your faulty code, `smallBottle` is assumed to be the event object - which certainly has no `fillAndTransferTwice` method. And this is why you get the error complaining that it is not a function (because `undefined` is indeed not a function).

You simply want to run the `fillOneLiter` function when the click happens, with arguments that you already know in advance. This is what the corrected version does.